# What to call someone who complains about you replying too late?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What do you call someone is too impatient or complains about another person taking long to reply back to them?

Comment: What would _you_ call them?

Comment: My instinct would be to call them precisely what you called them in your question:  *impatient* or a *complainer*.  Or, if you want to speak about them slightly more generally, *unreasonable*.

Comment: Those seem to be two different questions. How about 'injured party' if the reply is too late (eg '... apply by the last day of May to be considered for the post ... in a letter sent in June).

Comment: Maybe you could coin a new term.  How about lag averse?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to figure out a term that is less negative, you could describe them as...

> **Overeager**
> əʊvərˈiːɡə/
> adjective
>
> 1. excessively eager or keen.